# Class hash does not exist laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am upgrading laravel from 5.3 to 5.4.  I tried both way, but updating composer or download new laravel 5.4 and paste directory in it.

I am getting error:

> In Container.php line 729:
>
> Class hash does not exist

Note: Composer update successfully.

Comment: Have you added any service providers to your `config/app.php` that you have since uninstalled?

Comment: No, I used the same which i used in 5.3

Comment: Provider:
Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,

Aliases:

'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,

In config/app.php

Comment: try to use `\Hash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please us following.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following when error comes same as below picture
[image]

Now go to project (root folder) -> storage -> framework
and check that there are views folder exist or not. If there are views folder (C:\xampp\htdocs\project\storage\framework\views) not exist then you should create new folder views and then run your project.

In my case, 3-4 months facing issue and then i saved my project.